# Weird line on radio buttons when displayed on a iPhone

Tags: html, css, iphone, styles

I've made a donation form with radio buttons. It's fully styled with CSS.
When i open it on a Windows computer / android phone / iMac, everything looks fine.
But when i open it on a iPhone i get some strange lines where the radio button is.
The lines have a weird position, but that's because of the padding.

Does anybody know how i can get rid of the lines on the iPhone?

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Might be some box-shadow on its parent. Try USB debugging it

Comment: Can you include the CSS code are you using?

Comment: There is another behind "Steun via IDEAL" so I think it's not related to radio buttons, there are three text inputs and three shadow like line maybe they are related

Answer (score 1):

That is caused by the original radio button's border. You can eliminate it with

```css
input[type="radio"] {
    border: none;
}
```